# Virtualization aware switches

Tags: virtualization

According to http://www.cisco.com/en/US/solutions/collateral/ns340/ns517/ns224/ns892/ns894/white_paper_c11-525307.html

Each virtual machine is given a dedicated network interface card. My question is, how do a server containing about 10 virtual machines, ever support 10 NIC's ?

Answer (score 1):

Those NICs are probably virtual. Packets from them are routed to the physical NIC(s) and the other way around. It's pretty much the same thing as you get in modern WiFi routers: at home you only have one Ethernet port from your Internet Service Provider, it's in the modem. You connect your router to it, but your router may have 2+ Ethernet ports to which you can connect multiple PCs.

They can be physical too and either be directly accessible to VMs or indirectly.

Comment: is SR-IOV technology needed in this case ?

Comment: SR-IOV isn't necessary, but it can improve performance. That's the whole point of its existence, less overhead in the host OS.

Comment: then are you saying that a normal NIC card with a virtualization aware switch can do the job for us ?

Comment: Iam having a question, then how can Virtual machines make direct connections with the NIC if it does not support S-IOV? It has to have some sort of direct I/O capability right ?